# How to make the file sent only once and not duplicated? Function App and blob storage container

Tags: email, containers, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I have this function App and I get the file once when I put one file on blob storage container!
when I put 2 files, I get 4 files in my email addressee and the same file twice ! when I put 3 files I get 9 files , the same file duplicated 3 times , and when I put 4 files I get 16 files and  the same file duplicated 4 times , how to resolve this ?

this my function app :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `Send an email (V2)` connector is in for each loop of Lists blob's `value`, you are receiving everything in duplicate as it iterates all over the folder/container that you have set. After reproducing from our end this was working when we have changed Get Blob's Blob path to `List of Files Path` of `When a blob is added or modified (properties only) (V2)` and also use `When a blob is added or modified (properties only) (V2)` content in `Send email` too, we could receive emails on current item one time.

[image]

Here is the schema of my logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Get_blob_content_(V2)_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(triggerBody()?['Path']))}/content",
                    "queries": {
                        "inferContentType": true
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Lists_blobs_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Lists_blobs_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/foldersV2/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('JTJmY29udGFpbmVyMQ=='))}",
                    "queries": {
                        "nextPageMarker": "",
                        "useFlatListing": false
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmY29udGFpbmVyMQ==": "/container1"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Body": "<p>@{triggerBody()}</p>",
                        "Subject": "@triggerBody()?['DisplayName']",
                        "To": "<To email id>"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_blob_content_(V2)_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_blob_is_added_or_modified_(properties_only)_(V2)": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/triggers/batch/onupdatedfile",
                    "queries": {
                        "checkBothCreatedAndModifiedDateTime": false,
                        "folderId": "JTJmY29udGFpbmVyMQ=="
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmY29udGFpbmVyMQ==": "/container1"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "splitOn": "@triggerBody()",
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/***/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/***/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work for me, I get the same result, I receive the files duplicated !

Comment: Can you show me the whole schema if you don't mind !

Comment: @WassimAntri Sure, Can you please check the updated answer

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain to you  correctly.

Comment: I need to see how you did it (your function app) so I check what's the difference between my app and your app to realise what should I fix exactly ?
thanks in advance

Comment: As I have explained in my answer, you need to get both the connectors (i.e., get blob content and send an email) out of the for loop, but it wouldn't be possible if you are using List of Blobs "path" in get blob content and send an email. To be exact try removing your List of Blobs and then use variables that I have mentioned in the solution.

Comment: Yeah, I get it now, thank you it's working for me now !